# Wireless communication between two arduino boards

Tags: arduino

I am working on a project where I need to wirelessly communicate two arduino boards. One arduino will be used as a beacon to relay info for others. The one relaying information will have to be burried in ground say 6 inches beneath surface level. The distance between two boards cane be around 10 feet. I learned arduino Wireless SD Shield is a way to establish wireless communication but it also says that communication is going to be in line of sight. But in my matter, there is no line of site. The setup has to be one point to many points as the beacon will send information to many points.

How I do that? Can someone give link to some latest tutorial for such setup.

Comment: You might have to do an experiment to see how reliably it works. The ground could be wet or dry.

Comment: @Andyaka: once I made one, will have to do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wireless module isn't included with this shield, and you are free to choose which module you want to use, and can for instance choose a module from xbee that uses the 2.4GHz band. In that case, you can safely bury it 6 inches into the ground and communicate the required 10 feet.

The line of sight mentioned is for maximum distance of (normally) 300 feet. In-doors its typically limited to about a 100 feet due to walls and such reducing the signal strength. (It's the same as for a regular Wi-fi signal).

Comment: thank you very much. Can you please give me link for a latest tutorial for this kind of setup that lists the required parts too. Its going to be a one point to many points setup as beacon will serve many clients.

Comment: Arduino site tells that XBee-PRO 802.15.4 use the IEEE 802.15.4 networking protocol for fast point-to-multipoint or peer-to-peer networking. I think this is the module that I need to use with arduino wireless shield.

Answer (score 1):

I am not too familiar with that specific shield but as far as I know, most of these shields work at 2.45 GHz band (e.g. Xbee shield). In that case, 6 inches of soil should not make a huge difference, especially when the total distance is 10 or so feet.

Comment: what about line of sight matter.

Comment: LOS is not needed for RF communication, only to maintain the maximum communication distance (e.g. 300 ft). If you need to communicate over 10 ft, LOS does not matter